# HOW show list all variables initialized by SET operator?

Tags: mysql

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SET @good = 10;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'good';
    Empty set (0.07 sec)
```

HOW show list all variables initialized by SET operator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL, use this:

```
select * from performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread;
```

## MySQL Demo:

```
mysql> SET @good = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @bad = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread;
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| THREAD_ID | VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
|     36922 | bad           | 0              |
|     36922 | good          | 10             |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For MariaDB, it is not supported so far:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-user_variables-table/

***`The USER_VARIABLES table will be introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0 as part of the user_variables plugin.`***

Comment: MariaDB [test]> select * from performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread' doesn't
exist

Comment: It seems that MariaDB doesn't support this so far.